# Thin configuration file for HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: ruby, thin

I'm trying to configure both HTTP and HTTPS on thin. I have this configuration file:

```
environment: production
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 9292
chdir: /home/[user]/[mySinatraAPP]
pid: tmp/thin.pid 
rackup: config.ru 
log: server.log 
max_conns: 1024 
timeout: 30 
max_persistent_conns: 512 
daemonize: true
```

I activate the ssl option with:

```
thin -C thin.yaml start --ssl
```

But it only activates HTTPS and not HTTP. Any idea of the path I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about two thin processes? One **without** `--ssl`, and hence bound to port 80, and the other **with** `--ssl` and bound to port 443?

To be honest, I'd probably be more tempted to use Apache as a reverse proxy between the users and thin, and then have 2 virtualhost sections in your apache configuration.